# Campaign Member Statuses not Automatically Created in Test Classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, campaign

If I create a new Campaign through the Salesforce UI, the Campaign Member Statuses of Sent and Responded are created automatically.

But when I insert a Campaign in a test class no Campaign Member Statuses are automatically created. (I am doing this in a new scratch org with no existing flows/triggers on Campaign)

```
@isTest 
private static void campaignInsertTest() {
    Campaign c = new Campaign(Name='Test Campaign');
    insert c;
    System.debug([SELECT Id,Label FROM CampaignMemberStatus]);//DEBUG|()
}
```

When I run that same exact code from Execute Anonymous I get a different result.

```
Campaign c = new Campaign(Name='Test Campaign');
insert c;
System.debug([SELECT Id,Label FROM CampaignMemberStatus]);//DEBUG|(CampaignMemberStatus:{Id=01Y3G000000Z8aGUAS, Label=Sent}, CampaignMemberStatus:{Id=01Y3G000000Z8aHUAS, Label=Responded})
```

Is there something I need to do in the test class in order for Campaign Member Statuses to be automatically created?

Comment: Hi @Windam,  Did you check using `SeeAllData=true`. We know that it is not advisable but can you check if it is returning any data for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CampaignMemberStatus records are even created in test class as well same as your anonymous block code but you won't be able to query them . If you need those queries you have to use  `SeeAllData=true` in your test class to access them.

Generally the best practise is not to use it.

Comment: or, use selector classes and mock the selector for CampaignMemberStatus using dependency injection to avoid the SeeAllData issue